# What should Mono-B put in sideboard against GW-Tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

My brother plays a Mono-Black standard-format deck against me often. He has some big threats in there like [Phyrexian Obliterator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214386), [Sheoldred, Whispering One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214382) and [Lashwrithe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214359) as well as many cards with phyrexian mana to fuel his rage extractors. Smaller creatures I see all the time are [Porcelain Legionnaire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218043) and [Vault Skirge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=217984). In addition to that he has some discard spells for control. I don't have his exact deck list but that's what I am facing all the time.

The main idea is to stall me as long as he needs to get his threats out and overwhelm me in the end. This works really well against most of my decks and compete almost on even ground against my strong decks like "elves", "tempered steel" and "solar flare". His weakest match up at the moment is against my GW-Token deck, similar to [this one](http://puremtgo.com/articles/wg-tokens-standard), except that I have 4 [Oblivion Rings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234567) in the main deck and no [Timely Reinforcements](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220074).

What should he put into his sideboard to be able to compete against this deck? I would suggest some [Ghost Quarters](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220371) to deal with [Gavony Township](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233242) but this still leaves him with the problem of [Shrine of Loyal Legions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=206347), [Intangible Virtue](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243217) and [Elspeth Tirel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212241) which he usually has no real answer to. Especially when I use my [Oblivion Rings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234567) on his threats it is game over.

Which Mono-Black or Phyrexian-Mana spells can address this problem in Standard (Scars - Innistrad - M12)?

Comment: Oblivion Ring, the bane of any deck playing against it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black Sun's Zenith and Ratchet Bomb can help gain some time and clear the way for his creatures to hit.

If the planeswalkers and the Shrine are still a problem, Hex Parasite should really help fix that!

You can also look at Pro Tour Honolulu deck lists for inspiration. I'd recommend you to watch Jasper Johnson-Epstein's mono-black [deck tech](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/eventcoverage/ptdka12/videodt5) — deck list can be found [here](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/eventcoverage/ptdka12/stddecks) (search for his name).

Comment: Ratchet Bomb really does work wonderfully against tokens.

Comment: After seeing Honolulu T8 I am srsly considering maindecking ratchet bombs for the forseeable future :)

Answer (score 1):

Some popular options (besides those mentioned by @rahzark) are as follows:

- [Sever the Bloodline](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=245194) - exiling all of the tokens of one type (with flashback!) is pretty nice, especially if they're your only fliers and he manages to get a Vault Skirge with Lashwrithe.
- [Curse of Death's Hold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227075) - getting this if you don't have an Intangible Virtue pretty much ruins your day, but otherwise it's a pretty expensive cancellation of said Intangible Virtue. Nonetheless, it's probably worth sideboarding anyway because of its effectiveness in the current meta.

Another option is [Corrosive Gale](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230075) - however, it's pretty specific, and doesn't really work well enough given that Lingering Souls has flashback and your threats can be of the flying or non-flying variety.

If he's willing to splash red, he does have a few more options, but that is a big commitment (especially if he's running things like Obliterator):

- [Whipflare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194383) for non-artifact creatures
- [Slagstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214054) for *everything*
- [Rolling Temblor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249660) for a worse version with flashback

Given all of this, I'd say Sever the Bloodline is actually the best option outside of Black Sun's Zenith and Ratchet Bomb.

Comment: "Especially if he's running things like Obliterator" -- I'll say! "Slagstorm deals 3 damage to each creature; also, you sacrifice three permanents" is not a good plan.

Comment: @AlexP hopefully that would get sideboarded out if Slagstorm was necessary. Obliterator is great and all, but he's not really useful against tokens.

Comment: Actually I think Obliterator is a million times better. It can kill a Planeswalker really fast and make the opponent sacrifice several tokens. You shouldn't be playing a BBBB creature in a red/black deck, though :p

Comment: Ah, and it's not Midnight Haunting that has flasback! That would be Lingering Souls.

Comment: @rahzark the whole idea of tokens is a massive number of pumpable creatures that are easy to get out, though - with the flashback on Lingering Souls and Elspeth's -2, they'll be able to recover from that fairly easily.

Comment: @IanPugsley That's why destroying the Planeswalker is so important. I think Obliterator is way better at that. In the described situation it's probably the most effective solution at 4 mana (assuming a land drop every turn that would make it come in a turn earlier than Elspeth)

Comment: @rahzark Trying to keep Elspeth alive would be a pretty bad play - I see it as an easy three soldier for 3WW and extra turn with an Obliterator not attacking a player. That turn five commitment to attacking Elspeth with Obliterator means taking probably 8-12 damage from other tokens if Obliterator isn't left open as a blocker. If he is left open as a blocker, he's just asking to get O-ringed (he's asking to get O-ringed either way, really, but it's even meaner there).

Comment: @IanPugsley I agree with everything you said, yet I still think Obliterator is better than the Slagstorm.

Comment: @rahzark **In this deck**, I agree (which is why I don't actually recommend it). Slagstorm is still a *very* versatile card - it can take out a Planeswalker at 3 or less loyalty counters, or wipe these fliers. For mono-B I'd say no; for anything actually running red, I'd say yes.

Answer (score 1):

Proven answers:

- [Ratchet Bomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205482): against Tokens, this is a **one-sided sweeper**; you can also ratchet it up to destroy cards like anthems or O-Rings.
- [Black Sun's Zenith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214061): a regular ol' sweeper.
- [Curse of Death's Hold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227075): great weenie hate, although somewhat ineffective in this anthem-happy format unless you can actually deal with the anthems.
- [Ghost Quarter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220371): kills Inkmoths and utility lands; I'd maindeck these if you plan to run them, unless you're already got Inkmoth Nexus watering down the colors in the maindeck; almost every Standard deck has lands you want to kill, though.

Niche cards:

- [Sever the Bloodline](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=245194): like a more limited Ratchet Bomb against decks that tend to just have one type of token, but it does double as spot removal in a pinch.
- [Hex Parasite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218008): kills planeswalkers (also Illusions), keeps Shrines (of Burning Rage, but also Loyal Legions) in check; could probably be maindecked.
- [Surgical Extraction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233041): a niche solution, but it fixes "I can answer this once but it's gonna suck if my opponent finds another one"; much better if you're playing Snapcasters or hand-peeking cards, though.

Answer (score 0):

Despise is a great early card that can potentially remove some big threats